# Angular momentum conservation laws and GHZ article (Greenberger et al 1990)

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

Can anyone recommend a good book or an online source on angular momentum conservation laws in decay processes?

I'm writing a master's thesis concerning Bell inequalities and currently working on GHZ theorem. In the paper by Greenberger et al http://www.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/~yorks/qm12/ghsz.pdf , on page 1134 there's a decay of a spin 1 particle into two spin 1 particles and a subsequent decay into four spin 1/2 particles.

Spin conservation in the basic Bohm version of EPR is understandable but I cannot grasp how it goes in this case and what the practical decay process might be. As of yet, I haven't investigated experimental realizations of GHZ in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a pair of spin one particles going off in opposite directions one with $S_z$ of $+ \hbar$ and the other with $S_z$ of $- \hbar$. And in a superposition of the form $\frac{\vert +1\rangle\vert -1\rangle-\vert -1\rangle\vert +1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$. When each spin 1 decays into a pair of spin 1/2 you get
 $$\frac{
\vert\frac{1}{2}\rangle\vert\frac{1}{2}\rangle
\vert\frac{-1}{2}\rangle\vert\frac{-1}{2}\rangle
-
\vert\frac{-1}{2}\rangle\vert\frac{-1}{2}\rangle
\vert\frac{1}{2}\rangle\vert\frac{1}{2}\rangle
}{\sqrt{2}}$$
And the second decay shouldn't be all that mysterious.